# How can I make a list with variable parameter size inside of a custom environment?

Tags: environments, itemize, templates, optional-arguments, arguments

I have a custom environment that I am using as part of a template. Right now this is the code for the template file.

```
%-----------------------------------------------------------
%    customtemplate.cls
%-----------------------------------------------------------

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}

% New environment for the long list
\newenvironment{twenty}{%
    \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}ll}}{%
    \end{tabular*}
}

\newcommand{\twentyitem}[3]{%
    \parbox[t]{\textwidth}{%
        \textbf{#2}%
        \hfill%
        #1\\%
        #3\vspace{\parsep}%
   }\\
}
```

In a `.tex` file the command is called like so:

```
%-----------------------------------------------------------
%    somefile.tex
%-----------------------------------------------------------

\begin{twenty}
    \twentyitem{2013}{This is an example}{lorem ipsum etc\ldots}
\end{twenty}
```

gives this output:

[image]

The behavior I would like is this, where I can have as many or as little arguments as I want, with the condition that the first 3 are required. "meaning there needs to be at least one item in the list"

```
%-----------------------------------------------------------
%    somefile.tex
%-----------------------------------------------------------

\begin{twenty}
    \twentyitem{2013}{This is an example}{lorem ipsum etc\ldots}{as}{many}{as}{possible}
\end{twenty}
```

[image]

I made an attempt at putting an itemize in the template code but was unable to figure out how to make a variable number of arguments with the precondition that there must be at least 3. None of what I tried would actually compile.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Since you are just using a `\parsep` to separate items, why don't you just incorporate all the items into argument `#3`, using `\par` as the separator?  That is, `\twentyitem{2013}{This is an example}{lorem ipsum etc\ldots\par as\par many\par as\par possible\par}`

Comment: @Steven B. Segletes When using a \par separated list as the 3rd argument I lose the bullets from the itemize environment. Also when working with large lists it seems to me like having multiple arguments would be better than parsing 1 very long argument.

Comment: Well, your `twenty` environment had no `itemize` inside of it.  How about (assuming you add the `itemize` inside of `twenty`, something like `\begin{twenty}
    \twentyitem{2013}{This is an example}\item lorem ipsum etc\ldots \item as \item many \item as\item possible
\end{twenty}`

Comment: Note also that since your `\twentyitem` invokes a `\parbox`, it will not break across pages, regardless of how long it is.

Comment: You say "when working with large lists it seems to me like having multiple arguments would be better than parsing 1 very long argument." That is the whole impetus for environments in preference to macros.  When the content is long and of indeterminate length, the use of an "argument" becomes very unwieldy.  To me, it looks as if a simple `itemize` environment would be sufficient.  Tell us why that does not work for you, and maybe we can resolve it in the context of an environment.

Comment: I understand what you are suggesting, but I'm not sure how to make the environment accept both `\twentyitem` AND `\item`.

Comment: My previous comment was about the `\par` separated argument being unwieldy. Your next suggestion about using them in conjunction is a very good idea, I'm just unsure how to implement the environment to allow both `twentyitem` and `item`

Comment: I cannot ascertain the purpose of the `twenty` environment (note that a `tabular` will not break across pages).  There is nothing that prevents two nested environments, you know... `\begin{twenty}\begin{twentyitem}\item...\item...\end{twentyitem}\begin{twentyitem}\item...\item...\end{twentyitem}\end{twenty}`

Comment: `\twenty` is an environment, (like `itemize`). analogously `\twentyitem` is a custom `\item` for the `twenty` environment. So it would look something like this. `\begin{twenty}\twentyitem{temp}{temp}\item...\item...\item...\end{twenty}` What I am confused about is writing the `\twenty` environment to accept 2 different types of `\item`, both itemize's and my custom `twentyitem`

Comment: If the template is important, why not give a link to the template and give proper attribution for the code?

Comment: Long lists will probably fail to provide a CV that can be read within 20 seconds, failing the whole purpose of the template.

Comment: @Johannes_B since you asked this is the link I used. https://www.latextemplates.com/template/twenty-seconds-resumecv. I didn't post it originally because I'm not using their code verbatim, just using it as inspiration to write my own to my own specifications.

Comment: So, summing it up, a template for desaster.

Comment: Do you have anything helpful to add to the discussion? Or are you just deciding to be an internet troll? I don't know about you but I learn best by examining how others do things. I don't see anything wrong with wanting to learn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing at what the OP really wants, but am convinced, regardless, that nested environments are preferable to long-argument macros, for what he wants.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem,lipsum}
\newenvironment{twenty}{
  \noindent\hrulefill The Twenty Environment\hrulefill
  \begin{itemize}[itemindent=1em,label={}]}{
  \end{itemize}
  \hrulefill End of The Twenty Environment\hrulefill
}
\newenvironment{twentyitem}[2]{
  \item #2\hfill#1\begin{itemize}}{\end{itemize}}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{twenty}
\begin{twentyitem}{2013}{This is an example}
\item Blah
\item blah blah
\item lah blah blah
\end{twentyitem}
\begin{twentyitem}{2014}{This is a second example}
\item Blah
\item blah blah
\item lah blah blah
\end{twentyitem}
\end{twenty}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry if my additional explanation was confusing, this is exactly what I was looking for, thank you. I tunnel-visioned on making an argument list without considering better alternatives.

Answer (score 3):

Environments are allowed to have arguments, so you can have something like this:

```
\begin{twenty}{This is an example}{2013}
  lorem ipsum etc\ldots,
  as,
  many,
  as,
  possible
\end{twenty}
```

produce something like this:

[image]

The `twenty` environment takes two arguments and then it turns the *comma separated list* in the environment body into an enumerate environment (personally, I'd just use `\item` commands, which is much easier to code, but the syntax above is possible and seems closer to what the OP asks for).

Here is the full code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{environ}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \l_tmp_seq
% usage: \begin{twenty}{left header}{right header}  csv of items\end{twenty}
\NewEnviron{twenty}[2]
{\noindent\textbf{#1}\hfill#2% left and right headers
 \begin{itemize}% start the itemize environment
   \seq_set_split:NnV \l_tmp_seq {,} {\BODY}% split the body into \l_tmp_seq
   \item\seq_use:Nn \l_tmp_seq {\item}% write the list
 \end{itemize}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{twenty}{This is an example}{2013}
  lorem ipsum etc\ldots,
  as,
  many,
  as,
  possible
\end{twenty}

\end{document}
```

Some comments.

- The environment is defined using `\NewEnviron` from the [environ](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/environ) package because this allows us to take the `\BODY` of the environment and use it as a comma separated list.
- Normally, I would use `\docvslist` from the [etoolbox](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) package to process the list but that does not work in this case, presumably because our list is "paragraph shaped". Instead, I use [expl3/xparse](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xparse) to split `\BODY` into its components and then build the `enumerate` environment.
- I have used a comma as a separator but you could, for example, use `@` by editing the code above so that line 10 reads:

  ```
  \seq_set_split:NnV \l_tmp_seq {@} {\BODY}
  ```

**Edit**

Rather then processing a comma separated list a more sensible format is to use a mark-up like syntax:

```
\begin{twenty}{This is an example}{2013}
  - lorem ipsum etc\ldots
  - as
  - many
  - as
  - possible
\end{twenty}
```

Here is the modified code, which also adjusts the spacing:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \l_tmp_seq
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \regex_split:nnN { nVN }
\NewEnviron{twenty}[2]
{\noindent\textbf{#1}\hfill#2
 \begin{itemize}[nosep]
   \regex_split:nVN {  \B-\B  } { \BODY } \l_tmp_seq
   \seq_pop_left:NN \l_tmp_seq \l_tmpa_tl % pop initial blank
   \item\seq_use:Nn \l_tmp_seq {\item }
 \end{itemize}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{twenty}{This is an example}{2013}
  - lorem ipsum etc\ldots
  - as
  - many
  - as
  - possible
\end{twenty}

\end{document}
```

With the new spacing the output is now:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for showing me an example of delimiters, While I'm not using them in this instance, I can certainly appropriate this for other code down the road.